# UICollectionView don't reuse cell on ios 8 and ipad air 1

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm not using storyboard, everything is done by code..
and when I scroll the UICollectionView.. after it reusing correctly..some cells..
than it happen :

-the cell initWithFrame is being call

-new gray hair appear on my head.

I read other q/a and check maybe it's something with threads but all the reloadData is on the main thread.

any directions ?

Comment: Can you show some code ;P?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's your code, so I'll propose how do I do it:

```
// somewhere in eg viewDidLoad
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
[self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellId];
```

And later the delegate:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:MyCellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // do something with your cell, set title or anything

    return cell;
}
```

There is another possibility. Your cell, as it's reusable, will have already saved previous properties. So if you did something like this:

```
if (iCanAddGrayHair) {
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hair"]]
}
```

Then do notice, that new cell will still have this image set! You need to add:

```
else {
    [cell.imageView setImage:nil];
}
```

To reset it from previous state. You can also override `prepareForReuse:` method of `UICollectionViewCell` class to reset the values (don't forget to call super).

Comment: the problem is the uicollectionView create NEW cell (initWithframe)
when calling dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier, after it already start reusing other cells.

what can make dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier to call initWithFrame again ? (when there is alreay cells for reuse)

I know there was a bug with this on ios 7. but this is ios 8

Comment: @user1105951 I've created a simple demo with above code. After scrolling only prepareForReuse is called, initWithFrame is not called. Beacuse you're not presenting any of your code, it's not possible to determine why it works wrong in your case. It's not iOS fault. Tested on iOS 8.3.

Comment: in the demo, if you load 100 cells, then tap on the status bar to trigger scroll to top, the uicollectionviewcell:dealloc is called ?